# Add more information in MiniProfiler's CustomTiming

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I am using MiniProfiler to monitor request to external APIs using `CustomTiming`s :

```
var externalApiClient = new ExternalApiClient();
using(MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("ExternalAPI","ExternalAPI.Method"))
{
    externalApiClient.Method();
}
```

This works well, but I would like to add more data like status codes, result counts... I haven't found anything built-in that would allow me to do this.

Have I missed something? What would be the best way? I could create a new class inheriting from `CustomTiming`, but looking at the [code](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/src/MiniProfiler.Shared/CustomTiming.cs), I fear this would not be reliable in the long run (with things like `[DataMember(Order = 8)]`).

Comment: Are you using v3 or the v4 beta?

Comment: I'm using v4 alpha.

Comment: I'm working on some Stack Overflow library stuff that came up unexpectedly. I'll answer soon as it's ready but TL;DR: we want this too. I'm going to support an optional dictionary on the custom timing for storing this stuff that only allocates if used. That way you an store `n` key/values with a timing if you so wish.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One place that you can add information to is a command string itself:

```
using (CustomTiming ct = MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("http", "GET http://foo.bar"))
{
    var response = await http.GetAsync("http://foo.bar");
    var bytes = (await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Length;

    // Command string will look like "GET http://foo.bar OK 50301[B]"
    ct.CommandString = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}[B]", ct.CommandString, 
                                     response.StatusCode, bytes);
}
```